# How can I update my app to make it compatible with older ios versions?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I just published a wkwebview app. But the app is only compatible with ios 15.0 and above. Please tell me, how can I update my app to make it compatible with older ios versions?

Comment: Change the deployment target to a lower iOS version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the deployment target here ( here ios 12 for example ) [image]